# Undefined Index for Valid key from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

While parsing a CSV file(I have used a Class found on Google), I ran into a problem. Here is an example of an array made from a .csv file(print_r):

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [﻿Site] => ViralNova
                [Impressions] => 104719
                [CTR] => 0.30%
                [Clicks] => 311
                [Average CPC] => $ 0.400
                [CPM] => $ 1.19
                [Conversion Rate] => 1.29%
                [Actions] => 4
                [CPA] => $ 31.100
                [Spent] => $ 124.40
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [﻿Site] => TMZ - Desktop
                [Impressions] => 103276
                [CTR] => 0.29%
                [Clicks] => 295
                [Average CPC] => $ 0.400
                [CPM] => $ 1.14
                [Conversion Rate] => 0.68%
                [Actions] => 2
                [CPA] => $ 59.000
                [Spent] => $ 118.00
            )
)
```

The Problem is that I cannot use the "Site" index. Whenever I try to, I get this notice:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Site in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\panel\update\assets\php\core\core-ajax.php</b> on line <b>104</b><br />
```

Line 104 being:

```
print $data[0]['Site'];
```

Also,

```
print $data[0]['Impressions'];
```

or

```
print_r($data[0]);
```

works without any problem and I get the correct value/array.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do: `var_dump($data)` and look at the output in the source code! <- Show that

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/kt6iAzCZM6ymbFkDsaARfp

Comment: You have an extra space and therefore your index is `' Site'` not `'Site'`. Do `echo $data[0][' Site']` and see if it works.

Comment: It is not working kidA. Undefined Index:  Site

Comment: It should work if you use `[' Site']` instead of `['Site']`. Tested it on my local and worked fine.

Comment: It is definitely not working..

Comment: It was not a space. But you were right. There was a character there... Please post it as an answer and I will approve it as the correct one. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Acc. to me your code is running fine. 
this problem is occur when in loop in a point your index is missing.

to resolve this issue..

use this..

```
<?php 
if($data[0]['Site']){
    print $data[0]['Site'];
}

// Also

if($data[0]['Impressions']){
   print print $data[0]['Impressions'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Surely you meant `if (isset($data[0]['Site']))`?